# Controlling a Raspberry Pi car

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make my raspi car controllable with my keyboard. I managed to do that but I stumbled upon a bug and I don't know how to solve it.

This is my code :

- motorControl contains the functions for the car movements : init() forward() reverse() turn_right() turn_left()

I also added an Ultrasonic Sensor to my car :

- distance_sensor contains the function that measures the distance between the sensor and a target object.

  ```
    import pygame
    from motorControl import *
    from distance_sensor import distance_Ultrasonic
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

    init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([240, 160])

    def check():
        dist = distance_Ultrasonic()
        while ( dist <= 3):
            dist = distance_Ultrasonic()
            stop()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    check()
                    turn_right()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    check()
                    turn_left()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    check()
                    forward()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    check()
                    reverse()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    stop()
                    pygame.quit()
            elif event.type ==  pygame.KEYUP:
                print('No key pressed')
                stop()
  ```

What I want to do here is when clicking on one of the keypads, the check() function will be called first to check if the distance is OK, then it moves forward, reverse or whatever..

But the problem here when holding down a keypad :
For example if I hold down the UP ARROW of my keyboard, the program calls check() as expected to check the distance then moves forward if the distance was ok. As I approach a target object, the car does not stop and hits the target. So apparently when holding down the UP ARROW, I'll be stuck in the forward() function without calling check() every single time. How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that even if `check` decides you should stop, you go ahead and do the motion anyway.  `check` needs to do a one-time check, and return True or False to tell the caller whether to proceed.  For example:

```
def check():
    if distance_Ultrasonic() <= 3:
        stop()
        return False
    return True

while True:
    check()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                check():
                turn_right()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                check()
                turn_left()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if check():
                    forward()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if check():
                    reverse()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                stop()
                pygame.quit()
        elif event.type ==  pygame.KEYUP:
            print('No key pressed')
            stop()
```

This assumes that "turn_right" and "turn_left" don't actually have any forward motion, so if you hold "right", you just want it to spin forever.  I don't how you want to handle reverse.  If the sensor is looking forward, then you have no way to know when to stop.